# Removing borders in accordion bootstrap angularjs

Tags: css, less, angularjs-bootstrap

I'm trying to hide the border in each accordion group with panel and then accordion .inner but none of these works. Where could I find the class/id of the accordion or how would I go to remove this style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accordions are made of panels, so you need to override the CSS of panels. To make it not affect all your panels, you can add the `accordion` tag as CSS selector.

This should work:

```
accordion .panel {
    border-width: 0;
}
```

By the way, I assume that you make use of [UI Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) and not the normal Bootstrap CSS/JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

In current [UI Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/), the offending CSS rule selector and fix is below:

```
.panel-group .panel-heading+.panel-collapse .panel-body {
    border: none;
}
```